# regex isn't working in windows in python program

Tags: python, regex, windows

```
import subprocess, re
command = "netsh wlan show profile"
networks = subprocess.check_output(command, shell=True)
network_names_list = re.findall("(Profile\s*:\s)(.*)", "networks")
print(network_names_list)
```

This code is making a output of empty list instead of wlan profiles.

Comment: Your pattern contains "Profile", but your search string does not: that is only "networks". Perhaps you meant the variable `networks`?

Answer (score 2):

Do you mean

```
networks = subprocess.check_output(command, shell=True)
network_names_list = re.findall("(Profile\s*:\s)(.*)", networks)
#                                                      ^^^^
```

You had the string `"networks"` instead of the variable `networks` (which potentially holds your output).

Comment: It returns with this output, TypeError: cannot use a string pattern on a bytes-like object.